# Does stopping bluetooth service powers it off as well?

Tags: terminal, bluetooth, power-management

Other things being equal, which of the three computers (after executing respective commands on them) would use the most energy?
Which the least amount of energy?

**1.** `bluetoothctl power off`

**2.** `bluetoothctl power off && doas systemctl stop bluetooth`

**3.** `doas systemctl stop bluetooth`

Does stopping bluetooth service powers it off as well?

Comment: power off what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it receives a signal to exit, `bluetoothd` will execute its [`adapter_shutdown()` function](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/src/main.c#L1234), which includes [the line](https://elixir.bootlin.com/bluez/latest/source/src/adapter.c#L10807):

```
set_mode(adapter, MGMT_OP_SET_POWERED, 0x00);
```

In other words, it always switches the adapter power off on exit.

As a result, all the three commands you specified will cause the Bluetooth adapter to be powered off, so the power consumption after command #2 or command #3 will be equal.

If you use command #1, the `bluetoothd` process will remain running. It will probably spend its time sleeping, but the scheduler will still need to keep track of it, so the CPU will still have to spend a minuscule amount of power and processing time on `bluetoothd`: those would be available for other things if you used command #2 or #3 instead.

However, the difference is likely to be tiny.